# Ubuntu server stops working after a while

Tags: server, crash, plex

After around 4-5 hours, my Ubuntu server running plex media server stops responding. Here's all the server reacts when crashed:

- the server screen stays black with no command line interface displaying.
- keyboard is not responding/seems completely cut from power
- cannot access server via ssh
- plex server doesn't work anymore like all other services
- Computer still runs but can only be fixed by holding the power button pushed to force shutdown the computer and then reboot.

Comment: Was the server crashing before installing plex? Did the hardware run another OS before installing Ubuntu?